# Oversight Tasks setup in MS Project

Tags: project, ms-project, gantt-chart

## Overview

In MS Project 2019, I am having trouble with a task setup. I have one task (oversight) that will last the duration of the project. For example this may be one hour a day for a resource. For the remainder of the available work day, I want the resource to work on other tasks.

## Setup

My oversight task is has start/end link to the projects summary tasks, its set to manual. In my resource usage I see 1 hour per day being assigned.

For my other task, when I assign it to the resource, it says they are over allocated. I set it to automatic schedule but I just a bunch of warnings and then it schedules the task to finish by the end of the summary; starting with just enough duration to finish the work hours.

## Problem

This still causes an over allocation but also shifts everything wrong.

## Question

How can I have MS project have my resource to spend on the 7 hours per day on the task and 1 hour on the oversight task until the it is done?

The oversight task is weird as well, its 45 days at 45 hours (knowing we only work weekends) we would expect the oversight commitment be spread evenly at around 1 or so a day. However we only an hour or so a week and then when the task starts it goes to 12 hours per day. Nothing about this makes sense.

Comment: Bromax, A good question but not appropriate for the focus of this forum. This forum is focused on programming help and issues and nothing in your question relates to any type of programming. I suggest you re-post your question to the Project Tech community at: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/project/bd-p/Project. And if you do post to the Project tech community, a screen shot of how you have things set up will be very helpsul

Comment: As this question is not about programming, but rather how to use Microsoft Project, it belongs on the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site.